# Hostname in mobile application

Tags: extjs, phonegap

I'm new to phonegap applicationand I want to know how does the url concept works in phonegap.

In web application we can get the hostname from the url by writing `"window.location.hostname"`(extjs code)

So, I want to know how to get hostname in mobile app.

Comment: post what you have so can get assistance

Comment: i want to know how to get hostname in mobile application

Answer (score 0):

Extjs application uses a web app created by cordova to run, so you can continue to use:

> window.location.hostname

that returns the domain name of the web host.

Comment: Thanks..in chrome emulator i tested and it works. we have to test the same in actual device